# Unique jQuery click issue - stops firing after first click on same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, jquery-events

I'm experiencing a fairly unique problem that I have not see any information on... anywhere.
It seems that the click event breaks down on an element after the first click (not always on the second, there doesn't seem to be any consistency – other than the first click always fires) – once the click event stops working it requires two clicks (not a double click) for the click event to fire.

Here are some specifics:

on page load, I am parsing through a JSON string to populate X dynamically generated lists to be used similar to a dropdown menu. In the code, immediately after each “dropdown menu” is generated and displayed on the screen, I apply a `.click(function(){`...

Here is the suspect script
the variable “tags” represents an Object that is basically a collection of dropdown menus.

```
 $.each(tags, function(k, v){ 
v.display('div#tags'); 
var selector = '#' + v.getId(); 
if(v.isTabled()){ 
    selector += ' tr.Option td'; 
}else{ 
    selector += ' .Option';
} 

var narrowedProducts = []; 

$(selector).click(function(){ 
    $.each($('div.Select'), function(i,e){ 
        var temp = $(this).children('input').attr('value'); 
        narrowedProducts = Row.narrowProducts(temp.split('-'), narrowedProducts); 
    }); 

    if(narrowedProducts.length === 1){ 
        $('input#THEPRODUCT')
            .attr('name', narrowedProducts[0]) 
            .attr('value', narrowedProducts[0]) 
    }else if(narrowedProducts.length === 0){ 

        $('input#THEPRODUCT') 
            .removeAttr('name') 
            .removeAttr('value') 
    }else{} 

    narrowedProducts = []; return; 
}); 
 });
```

and the html for the dropdowns...

```
<div id="tags">
  <input type="input" id="THEPRODUCT" />

  <div class="Select Select-sizechart" id="sizechart">
    <span class="Display">Select a sizechart:</span><input type="hidden" name=
    "sizechart" />

    <table class="Selectable">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="TableHeading">
          <th>Size</th>

          <th>Comparable Size</th>

          <th>Bust</th>

          <th>Hip</th>

          <th>Back Length</th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="Option" rel="L" id="68435-68414-68416-68423">
          <td>L</td>

          <td>16-18</td>

          <td>43"-45"</td>

          <td>45"-47"</td>

          <td>43"</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="Option" rel="XL" id="68432-68437-68419-68428">
          <td>XL</td>

          <td>20-22</td>

          <td>47"-49"</td>

          <td>49"-51"</td>

          <td>44"</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="Option" rel="S" id="68433-68420-68425-68431">
          <td>S</td>

          <td>8-10</td>

          <td>36"-37"</td>

          <td>38"-39"</td>

          <td>41"</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="Option" rel="XS" id="68436-68417-68424-68429">
          <td>XS</td>

          <td>4-6</td>

          <td>34"-35</td>

          <td>36"-37"</td>

          <td>40"</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="Option" rel="M" id="68415-68418-68421-68427">
          <td>M</td>

          <td>12-14</td>

          <td>38.5"-40.5"</td>

          <td>40.5"-42.5"</td>

          <td>42"</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="Select Select-color" id="color">
    <span class="Display">Select a color:</span><input type="hidden" name="color" />

    <div class="Selectable">
      <div class="Option" rel="River" id="68435-68418-68420-68424-68428">
        River
      </div>

      <div class="Option" rel="Smoke" id="68432-68433-68414-68415-68417">
        Smoke
      </div>

      <div class="Option" rel="Punch" id="68436-68419-68423-68427-68431">
        Punch
      </div>

      <div class="Option" rel="Sandstone" id="68437-68416-68421-68425-68429">
        Sandstone
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any clue how to solve this to create a better user experience?

---

I looked into delegate (and live), but unfortunately I'm tied to using version 1.3.2 for reason outside of my control.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why the problem occurs, but if i was you, I'd would look into using a delegated click handler instead of binding the same click function to all these elements.

Try to read up on http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ - it might just solve your problem, or at least make your code perform better ;)